# Dynamic <Title> text and Link text in html

Tags: java, html, dynamic, href

In the below HTML code, I want the text "Page Title" to be dynamic. That is, how do I make this string dynamic based on values in a DB table?

The same thing for the text "Click Here". I want to make the text referring the link to be called from elsewhere instead of directly hard coding it here.

I already have a Java file (web service framework) in which I have assigned the value from the Db to a string variable. Now I need the syntax for this string so that when I change the value of the string in DB, the title text changes here. Same for the link text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click following link</p>
<a href="https://www.testsite.net" target="_self">Click Here</a>
</body>
```

Also, can I use the same method for XML `<title>` also for the title tag?

Comment: 1. This is not XML, this is HTML; 2. You need to have back-end to make it dynamic (the data needs to be taken from somewhere). 3. Yes, you can take it from DB, why not? 4. Ask specific question, nobody can help you with this.

Comment: Sorry. i corrected it.. I already have a backend struts framework and a table containing the titles i need. But i dont know how to call it here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make this dynamic and the easiest way is probably to use a templating library. I would not recommend jumping straight into databasing as you're probably going to want to create some mock data first, so you're not testing your database AND your API at the same time, which is just likely to make things confusing and make tracking down bugs very difficult.

Some common templating frameworks include [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and something called [pug](https://pugjs.org/), which used to be called Jade.

The site for any templating library will usually have pretty solid basic tutorials, which should help you get started. I would also suggest looking into using a frontend framework like **Angular2** or **React** (I can't post more than two links here, but you should find them pretty easy to Google). I've used Angular2 a bit myself and the site has some really good beginners tutorials which should allow you to get started fairly easily, and as I recall, includes sections on templating and mock data.

Good luck :).

Comment: I am using a web-services framework that is extending struts. sorry for not mentioning this before.

Comment: all i need is the syntax which i am not able to find in google for the tags.     <title>syntax for assigned variable</title>

Comment: Which web services framework? You mentioned a web-services framework is extending struts, but not which one...

Comment: But does type of framework matter in this situation? I thought the syntax is relevant to the file type... .html or .xml and for backend, .java?

Comment: Different templating libraries use different syntax. For example, underscore uses `<%= %>` to insert a value into the DOM, whereas pug might use `#{}` for a similar purpose. Without knowing which particular framework you are using and what the templating syntax might be it would be difficult to answer the question. Unless web services frameworks work differently to the frameworks I am used to, which they may, and that's why I was asking you for the name of the framework: so I could help you research it.

Answer (score 1):

HTML in itself can only render static pages. If you want to generate dynamic content, then you can use any server side language like java, php, asp.net.

This is an example using JSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<%
    String dynamicPageTitle = "";
    dynamicPageTitle = getDyncamicTitle();
    ...
%>
<title><%=dynamicPageTitle%></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click following link</p>
<a href="https://www.testsite.net" target="_self">Click Here</a>
</body>
```

Comment: do you know this using xml please?

Answer (score 1):

```
This Is One Way To Provide Dynamic Title To Your Page , And Its Possible in Switch Case Also Try It Once 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
function titlefun(){
if(condition1){
 document.title="First Title";
 }
 else if(condition2){
 document.title="Second Title";
 } 
else{
document.title="Default Title";
 }
}
titlefun();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click following link</p>
<a href="https://www.testsite.net" target="_self">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: I Updated my Snippet This is finely working on my jsp Check once

Answer (score 0):

first you need to choose a server side language and then choose a database , 
suppose that you have chosen both of them , you need to a create A table in that database with 2 or 3 fields ( ID - URL - url_text ) 
then you are able to read that from your database and it wouldn't be hard coded in your HTML . this implies for the page title in the same way

Comment: yes I already have the mentioned requirements. But what i need is the syntax for calling this value to here from a java file where the value has been retreived from a DB and assigned to a variable.